# Why does integrating a fragment in xml fail with the error message of not being able to cast the fragment to view?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to create a fragment, that I can use as a backbutton in multiple activities (I know that Android has it's own backbutton but it's important for me to have a specific UI).

I try to integrate my backbutton in a AppCompatActivity by adding my xml:

```
<android.support.v4.app.Fragment
    android:name="com.myapp.uielements.BackButton"
    android:id="@+id/backbutton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
```

The code for the backbutton is:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
...

public class BackButton extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.backbutton, container, false);

        rootView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48: Binary XML file line #48: Class is not a View android.support.v4.app.Fragment
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48: Class is not a View android.support.v4.app.Fragment
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class android.support.v4.app.Fragment cannot be cast to android.view.View
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android.support.v4.app.Fragment` is a class name that is not a `View`. Layout inflater expects to see `View`s, or special tags such as `fragment`. To instantiate a fragment via XML layout, use `fragment`:

```
<fragment android:name="com.myapp.uielements.BackButton" ...
```